# How to use tar to compute a hash of a directory with excludes

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to compute a hash of a project directory using tar to compress and pipe into `sha1sum` and so far I have this:

`tar --exclude='.git' -cf - /path/to/my/project`

However, I end up getting an error message of "tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)" and "tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now".

But if I do `tar --exclude='.git' -cf - /path/to/my/project | sha1sum` it works! But I want to check if the .git folder is actually being excluded?

Comment: Why not use `git archive` to make the tar file?

Comment: @Shawn I'm using it to detect when to restart an application if I change code but something like inotify won't work between shared folders. Would `git archive` be better than tar?

Comment: It'll leave out git-specific files and anything not part of the repository. But this just became an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)... You should ask about your real problem you're trying to solve instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of files like this :

```
tar --exclude='.git' -cvf - /path/to/my/project 2> /tmp/list-files.txt > /dev/null
```